# vc++ 6.0 testing an unlicensed Activex ctrl by dlg application

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-6

I am using vc++ 6.0. I Have made an unlicensed activex ctrl application from app wizard (MFC activeX ctrl wizard for generating random drawing). When I am testing this Activex by ActiveX control test container,  all functions are working fine, but when I am testing it with dialog application, On calling any method of ActiveX it is giving error debug assertion failed. 
Program ......
File: winocc.cpp; 
line: 345

I am making an object of this ActiveX ctrl wrapper class in my testing dialog application and then calling method defined in this ActiveX ctrl.

My code:

```
CNewSquiggleAcX m_ClNewSquigg;
CFileDialog m_ldFile(TRUE);
    // Show the File open dialog and capture the result
    if(m_ldFile.DoModal()== IDOK)
    {
        CString m_sResults;
        m_sResults = m_ldFile.GetFileName();
        //m_ClNewSquigg.GetSquiggleLength();
        m_ClNewSquigg.LoadDrawing(m_sResults); // Error comes in this line
                                                          calling any activex function
    }
```

Please help me thanks in advance

Comment: You are possibly overestimating the number of SO users that still have that 15 year old copy of winocc.cpp and are willing to look at what line 345 says.

Answer (score 0):

The control needs to be instanciated. If you placed it on a dialog template then opening the dialog will create the control. The other approach is to call the CreateControl method, which you can find in the h file of the control's wrapper class.